# Using a Custom Single Sign On Authentication Service with Spring Security Core Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm working on a Grails application and want to integrate with a custom single-sign-on service (not CAS, but similar). I'm struggling to find all the pieces that I need to customize to make this happen. Can someone explain to me a general outline as to what I need to use to accomplish this? I've read the documentation on the plugin, but it assumes I know which beans to override and where to put all the needed files.

I've block-quoted what I think needs to be done based on my research below each point.

**Order of Operations**

**1-** The user requests secure content (everything is secure in the application for now)

> I believe this setting is in the Config.groovy file:

```
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
     '/**':['ROLE_ADMIN']
 ]
```

**2-** Spring Security checks to see if the user has a specific value set in a cookie provided by the authentication service

> I'm guessing I need to create an authentication filter, but I don't know where to put it or what it should look like.

- If they don't, the user is redirected to this custom SSO service, they login, once authenticated, the user is redirected back to my application (with a new cookie set)

**3-** Spring security checks for the cookie value and validates it against the custom service (via HTTP POST)

> From some research, I think that I need to use PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter, but I haven't been able to find any examples of how to do this.

**4-** The custom service returns a series of name/value pairs, a user then needs to be created in the local application database (or the timestamp of "lastLoggedIn" is updated if they user's data is already in the database)

> I believe this is done in the same PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter as number 3 or in a GrailsUserDetailsService

**5-** The user's authentication is cached in the session for a period of time (6-8 hours) so that re-validation against the SSO service doesn't need to occur every time the user requests a new resource.

> I'm not sure if this is something that's done inherently or if I need to add code to do this (and also set the session timeout)

Comment: I need something similar. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I used another language/framework